# Verilog D Flip Flop

Tags: verilog

I'm attempting to write a specific version of the D Flip Flop that uses NOR gates only:

Following is gate level diagram:

[image: NOR Gate D Flip Flop]

The code I'm using in Verilog:

```
module DFlipFlop(D,CLK,Q,QN);
    input D, CLK;
    output Q, QN;
    reg Q, QN, R, S;

always @(negedge CLK) begin
    R = ~(~(~(D|S)|R)|CLK);
    S = ~(~(D|S)|R|CLK); 
    Q = ~(R|QN);
    QN = ~(S|Q);
end

endmodule
```

I then uploaded the compiled program to a PLD and it's not flip flopping and I cannot figure out why. I've tried many different things already.

Note that I have to use the 4 equations in my program for R, S, Q, and QN.

Comment: Could you show us how you are clocking CLK, and any appropriate delays? Remember that with an `always` block, there will be a physical register inferred, which could disrupt the combinatorial feedback path that makes the flipflop function.

Comment: What do you mean? I apologize for my ignorance. I'm assigning the CLK input to a 50 MHz clock on my PLD.

Comment: This might be better at [electronics.SE]. I can't see anything wrong with the logic itself, aside from the fact that you already have a register/flipflop for *all of* R, S, Q, and QN by virtue of it happening inside an always block. If you eliminate the always block and use `assign` statements instead (e.g. `assign R = ~(~(~(D|S)|R)|CLK)`) does it work?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it right now. When I remove the always block, Q = D.

Comment: Could you specify the exact model of PLD/FPGA being used?

Comment: EP4CE22F17C6 - Cyclone IV E

Comment: On an FPGA there shouldn't be any need to manually create a flip-flop, and it's likely that it won't work as expected either. FPGA logic is more complex than simply logic gates (as it contains, at least on Xilinx, LUT, mux, possible reg or bypass through ANOTHER mux, routing, etc). I would recommend using the builtin register primitives and inference rather than trying to create your own register.

Comment: Again, I apologize. I understand what you mean by "register primitives" but I don't know what you mean in practice. Can you explain how I can do this in practice?

Comment: FPGAs contain dedicated flip-flops (called registers). If you declare a "variable" as `reg Q`, then it will automatically be placed in a flip-flop, and updated on a clock cycle. It also means that you will only be able to update it in an always block.

Comment: @hexafraction a `reg` is only instatiated as a register (flip flop) if it is assigned a value inside an `always @(posedge clk)` or `always @(negedge clk)` block. A reg inside a `always @*` block is a combinational signal, *not* a FF

Comment: @EEStudent1004 in the future, please describe the things you've tried. Also, simulating the design (such as with a waveform tool or a testbench) is good practice for debugging circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following line:

```
always @(negedge CLK) begin
```

What your circuit is actually creating is a seperate flip flop for each of `R`, `S`, `QN`, and `Q`., since you've declared tnis block as being *edge-triggered* (that's what `negedge CLK` means). If you want a purely combinational circuit (like what your gate-level diagram shows) you should be using an `always @(*)` block instead.

Note that Quartus II has a helpful tool called the **RTL Viewer** (*Tools->Netlist Viewers->RTL Viewer*) which shows a block-level schematic of your synthesised circuit. If you look at that, you'll see that you're actually creating four flip-flops (and some logic) with your code, not one.

Comment: But how would I ensure negedge triggering?

Comment: Your FF design should determine whether its a negedge or posedge triggered FF. Using `negedge` and `posedge` is used in design code for allowing RTL designers to not have to design FFs/registers themselves; just specifying the type they want and its behavior. In your case, you are explicitly designing the FF, so it should use combinational logic to represent the gates.